# feedly style table/scroll view

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiscrollview

I would like to implement feedly style UITableView / UIScrollView (but horizontal). I am searching for some info to do it in proper way but can't find any useful info.
If you don't know what I mean by "feedly style table view srolling" here is a link to a short [youtube movie](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GVpb-Dy3wjo&feature=em-upload_owner) with scrolling feedly screen

I would be grateful for any hints, ideas and open source projects which may help with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

I've found [PBGroupScrollController](https://github.com/piotrbernad/PBGroupScrollController) which makes exactly what I want. I'll give it a chance and test it. Even if it demands some improvements, it is a really good point to start! Thanks to [piotrbernard](https://github.com/piotrbernad).

Answer (score -1):

Stop looking for Table or Scroll views. Not even Collection Views.

Well, frankly, scrollviews could do the trick but you could easily get lost in the scroll view's geometry.

You need a way to manually scroll views (not UIScrollViews) by responding to touch gestures. I don't know a good example or tutorial by heard. But if you google for sample code for facebook style menus, then you will find some which do this sort of thing even horizontally.

The basic idea is either stacking view controllers with their views where you drag the topmost view (which I don't recommend) or having one view controller with a number of views (two or three) of which both/all fill the full screen and one lies on top of the other without beeing subview of the view underneath. 
In fact, all 2 or 3 views are siblings but the one on the top was added to the common superview later or was moved to top. I'd go for adding the view underneath first, then add the visible view and then add the view on top which is off screen.

So see one of these tutorials and learn, how to drag a view following touch gestures. It is surprisingly easy. It is just that there is no build-in control in cocoa touch available for that.

So do this for two views of which you want to be able to move one of them off the screen. For the users' convenience add the part that animates the top view off screen as soon as its dragging reaces some certain point near the top of the window.

Once you achieved that add a third view - if you want. The third view is off screen from the start and can be dragged down. You can apply pretty much the same logic but when the gesture starts on the very top region of the screen then it is applied to the view on top that is to be dragged down.

Once you can do that with 3 views - each of them of the size of the screen and one of them is either dragged off screen or one of them is dragged from the off into the screen, then you just need to add the infinite aspect of them.

Lets say you got an array of 10 or so objects that you want to be displayed and dragged into the screen or dragged off. Then you would only need 3 views to do that. 
For a start we have the situation where object 5 is visible
Ok, lets say view 1 (object 5) is off screen above the screen and may be dragged into the screen to hide view 2 (object 6) which is aligned to the screen. But when you don't drag view 1 (object 5) into screen then you drag view 2 (object 6) off screen. Just under view 2 (object 6) lies view 3 (object 7). View 3 (object 7) only comes into sight when view 2 (object 6) is dragged off screen.

So before you got this situation: 
view 1 shows object 5
view 2 shows object 6
view 3 shows object 7

Then the move takes place and in the very moment when the move is about to nearly finished then you add this "paging" effect that I mentioned already. You let the view that is being dragged animate to complete the view until it is either completely moved into the screen or off the screen.

If view 2 was moved off the screen then you just shift the objects displayed though the 3 views. After that you have reset all views. View 1, again ist hidden under view 2, both just fill the screen. View 3 is of the same size but located just above the screen. But they correlate to the objects displayd as follows: 
view 1 shows object 4
view 2 shows object 5
view 3 shows object 6

If the move was the other way around then you assign them as follows: 
view 1 shows object 6
view 2 shows object 7
view 3 shows object 8

Now you have got exactly the behaviour as shown in the video. You just have to decide if you want the views to scroll in an endless loop or if you want them to end. 
When you want them to end then think of a solution where a view 0 shows some sort of background and where the view 10 is final, meaning that no view 11 an be dragged into the screen.

Having them scolled in an endless manner may even be a bit easier. Juat use object 10 as object 0 and object 1 as object 11 and continue from there.

Comment: Tank you, for your answer. I'll do some more investigation and then let you know...